# Помогите найти ошибку в коде. vk.api

Tags: php, html, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, отладка

Пытаюсь отправить метод через PHP, однако мне тупо выдает ошибку 500.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Отправление, пожалуйста подождите...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=/">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="center">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">С Вами свяжутся в скором времени. Спасибо!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $message = "Новый заказ на сайте".PHP_EOL."Имя: ".$name.PHP_EOL."Телефон: ".$phone.PHP_EOL."Email: ".$email;

    send(123456789,$message); 

    function send($id , $message) {
    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?';
    $params = array(
        'access_token' => 'XXXXXX',  
        'user_id' => $id, 
        'message' => $message,
        'random_id' => 123456789
        'group_id' => 123456789
        'v' => '5.131',
    );
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($params)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    }

    ?>
```

Я уже битый час пытаюсь найти ошибку, но безуспешно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыты запятые в массиве после `random_id`

```
$params = array(
    'access_token' => 'XXXXXX',  
    'user_id' => $id, 
    'message' => $message,
    'random_id' => 123456789,
    'group_id' => 123456789,
    'v' => '5.131',
);
```

P.S. Лучше использовать для разработки IDE, они подсвечивают такие ошибки моментально